# .Maven_MavenInstallation/maven1: Permission denied

Tags: java, docker, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I keep getting this error while running my Jenkins. Currently using Maven in my project. I read through a previous post and recommended to enable permissions, which I did and still receiving the build failure. I am running Jenkins locally through a docker container.

```
Console Output
Console Output
+ /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven1 clean install
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/stock_app_no_gui_java@tmp/durable-982fa18f/script.sh: 1: /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven1: Permission denied
```

Attempted to grant permissions in the docker container.

Comment: Do you run as a docker user with permission to write in that location in the filesystem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.